# How can I insert new column where its value coming from another table?

Tags: sql

I have 2 different table (Table A and Table B).

Table A looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vU57A.png)

Table B looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gaZye.png)

I want to insert new column referred to productname in Table A, which its value based on productname in Table B.

How I can write the syntax?

Comment: are you trying to do this where?

Comment: dunno yet, this just a small practice--just like an exam. i was only instructed to create the syntax

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is to join the tables like this:

```
Select A.userid,
       A.itemid,
       A.insurance_amount,
       A.productid,
       B.productname
From A
Join B ON B.productid = A.productid
```